# Does limitToLast() only retrieve the last 5 or does it retrieve the entire object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've read that in Firebase when you query an object it pulls the entire object.  Meaning there is a cost for pulling that entire object.  In example.
Let us say I have myObject/1000RecordsAreHere.  When I query myObject

```
this.db.ref(`myObject`)
```

I would expect it does a query and returns all 1000Records.
If I run `.limitToLast(5)` would the cost be only for those 5 records? Or would it still pull the entire object and filter out only showing me the last 5?
I'm trying to see if it saves me the cost of the entire object being queried or if it's just filtering the data for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any query, you are only charged for the data that actually makes it to the client.  You are not charged for the entire set of data considered.

So, if you are able to modify a query in such a way that a subset of children end up in a snapshot, then you are paying only for that smaller set of data.